# How do I change the Default Design?

Tags: php, html, css, cross-domain, web-hosting

I have two different web designs(Created in PHP, HTML, CSS and JavaScript) Can I upload both and just switch them from time to time?

How do I redirect so i can choose what design will show when i open my website?

Comment: Make some kind of switch button in php and put the different layouts (LINKS) in a database

Comment: Does the HTML output differ between designs, or is it just stylesheets that differ?

Comment: I'm sorry let me rephrase my question: heres the scenario the current website content and design is say for example contant_1, now i want to upload another content and design named content_2, the question is how do i redirect in cpanel so that when i open my website it shows content_2 instead of the current content_1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code :

```
if(some condition here)
header('Location:design1.php');
else if(some condition here)
header('Location:design2.php');
```

or you can also use include function.

```
if(some condition here)
include("design1.php");
else if(some condition here)
include("design2.php");
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry let me rephrase my question: heres the scenario the current website content and design is say for example contant_1, now i want to upload another content and design named content_2, the question is how do i redirect in cpanel so that when i open my website it shows content_2 instead of the current content_1?

Comment: Header will redirect to your desired template's index.php page. Replace design.php , design2.php with the location of your template index pae. And Add this code in the root directory index.php page's top.@user3659548

Comment: Thanks it worked, do you have any other alternatives, for example website is purely HTML and not using PHP, is there a way?

Comment: use this code <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://submitmysites.blogspot.com/">   content= 1 means after 1 second it will redirect.Please don't forget to approve the answer and upvote it. here http:// before the domain name. I added but stack overflow make it as link.  Thanks.